# iCloud Photo Sharing - Not receiving invitation

Tags: iphone, icloud, photo-stream

I previously had an iCloud Photo Share album and then the pictures would stop appearing on my stream when the other member added new ones. We then removed me from the Stream to re-add. When we tried, I do not receive the invite. We tried my phone number and Apple ID. When I send the same person an invite to a "test" stream, they get the invitation right away.

I have other photo streams with other people and have not ran into any issues, just with this one person. They are able to send invites to other people for other albums as well. I am on iOS 9, they're on 8 but we had this issue when we were both on 8 as well.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 2):

The person who can't send the invite should check if mobile data is enabled for photos app
Maybe when they sent the invite to you, they didn't have wifi and mobile data was disabled.  but had wifi when they sent one to another person.

It happened to me. I couldn't receive and send invites. Once mobile data is enabled, the notification appeared that someone invited me and asked if I want to join. Now I can send and receive invites and all works as expected.
My iCloud photo library is not enabled, Only iCloud sharing is.

Comment: Thanks. This was true for me. But in my case, I did not set mobile data on but just resent the invitations when I happened to be on a Wi-Fi network and the invitations went out that time. I think your solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I've never experienced a similar issue, but these 2 steps won't hurt:

- Make sure both your iPhone and the other member's iPhone have iCloud Photo Sharing AND iCloud Photo Library turned on.
- Make sure you have the same settings set up on your Mac/iPad if you use any.

Also, if your shared iCloud Photo Album has more than 5,000 photos, you will need to make a new album to continue sharing.

Here's a great site for everything related to iCloud Photo Library:
https://tidbits.com/article/15584

[image: Tap on "Photos & Camera.]
[image: Make sure "iCloud Photo Sharing" is turned on.]

Comment: Still did not work. I'll have to contact Apple. It's weird because they get my invites and I get invites from other people just not this one person. All options are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple store was unaware of why this was happening. They ended up getting a new phone, signing into their iCloud and everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

Failed notifications may also be caused by missing choices in Settings>Messeges>Send&Receive>Send to and Receive from.

Because my preferred ‘friends & family’ email address is different than my Apple ID address, I needed to check both addresses ✔️as well as my iPhone #.